# Is it possible for unauthorized users to add some data into table?

Tags: backendless

I would like to allow for users to add some data that could be shared with other users. But I don't want users to register in order to do this. When they add some data,I just want user to type his name,I'll save it on backend and that's all. I've found at that registration could be turned off in Backendless. But seems like it is not so recommended and developers try to avoid this idea. This is relevant? Could there be some problems with publishing app in the future?

Comment: I suppose you could just have some "author" column in your data table and put there the user's name.

Comment: I am creating some quiz game,so I want to add the funtion that I described without registration. So you mean that it is ok to perform this idea?